# Wordpress for Linux - Max-age never set

Tags: linux, wordpress, azure

I have deployed a wordpress for linux app on an azure. It is working fine but I cannot get the Cache-Control header to set a max-age. 
I am using the w3 total cache plugin and have set the options "Set expires header" with a value of 31536000 and "Set Cache Control policy" to Cache with max-age for css,js and media.

I can then see all the correct changes made in the htaccess file.
But the max-age value never gets set in the response Cache-Control header

I ran a phpinfo() and results are as follows

```
Apache Version  Apache/2.4.25 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2g PHP/7.1.2
Apache API Version  20120211
Server Administrator    [no address given]
Hostname:Port   172.18.0.5:80
User/Group  www-data(33)/33
Max Requests    Per Child: 0 - Keep Alive: on - Max Per Connection: 100
Timeouts    Connection: 60 - Keep-Alive: 5
Virtual Server  Yes
Server Root /usr/local/httpd
Loaded Modules  core mod_so http_core prefork mod_authn_file mod_authn_core mod_authz_host mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_user mod_authz_core mod_access_compat mod_auth_basic mod_reqtimeout mod_filter mod_mime mod_log_config mod_env mod_headers mod_setenvif mod_version mod_ssl mod_unixd mod_status mod_autoindex mod_dir mod_alias mod_rewrite mod_php7
```

In the loaded modules there is no mod_expires listed which would probably indicate this may be the problem.

BUT how do I install this..?